# Upload git master branch to production server every 5 days

Tags: git, apache, bitbucket

I have an web app that we are developing as a team of about 4 using Git Flow and its all working nicely. Our master is (as we understand) treated as the production version of code available. As soon as master is updated it is uploaded to the production server where our customers have access.

We want to take master branch and upload it to our production server in its current state every 5 days. It is stored in BitBucket.

How can this be done?

Comment: Your CI engine should be able to do this.

Comment: Don't do that. Define some other, roughly weekly, milestone on which to push. Make sure that the visible repository contains completed changes, not half of the series of 17 patches because the automatic pusher kicked in.

Comment: Currently our master branch is carefully monitored so that it is only ever modified to enhance it in a stable way. In this respect, the issue is not on the risk of unintended consequences, but rather how to get the upload going?

Comment: What is the CI engine?

Answer (score 0):

There are hooks in git that can be used to attach custom actions to.  However, since you are wanting this to happen on a timed schedule instead of when certain events happen within git, I would write a script to pull the latest from production and deploy it.

Set this script to run on a schedule and your all set.

Comment: As far as I've gathered the best way currently is not automated, but rather to create a repository in the public facing release folder on our server which we can add as a remote and push updates to manually, but at the same time as modifying master branch. This way we get exactly the same environment as the master branch pushed up to both remotes at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

looking into http://jenkins-ci.org.  We do it and it works out great.

If you have any issues please let me know.. on twitter @JohnathanMSmith

You can have jenkins ci do it everytime the project has changes or on a time check..

Comment: I think SO is the place to let know any issue to find out how to solve it :)

Comment: sorry.. I did not mean dont post it here.  I mean post it and then follow the link to me